# Code block is not changing colour

Tags: bug, code-formatting

I was trying to edit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076638/how-to-decrease-spell-check-time-processing) question but I could not edit the code block using the normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> method. The code would not format properly, it stayed clumped together even after I applied <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. So I waited to see if it gets edited and some one managed to edit it. However I find that the colors for the keywords are not changed like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077106/is-not-allowed-as-an-instance-variable-name) one for instance. Is this a bug or do I have to change any settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without proper tag, the prettifier can't possibly know what language to apply. In such cases, either add the tag or force specific language by adding such line above the code block:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
```

I just did the later in the question you linked to.

[More details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Answer (score 3):

You were not able to format code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> because the OP wrote that [code in bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16076638/1). So you required to apply [four extra spaces manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/187824).